# How to increase android volley request Time Out

Tags: android, android-volley

I am using android volley to handle request & response. But when it takes time to process data in server end  it shows time out.I have tried to increase volley processing time . Some time app unfortunately stopped app when it process data & move to another pages.
Here is my volley code..

```
private void dosubmit() {
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray loginNodes = jsonObject.getJSONArray("executeNodes");

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    e("Err", error.toString());
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("request_code", "parem1");

            return params;
        }
    };
    new VoleyErrorHandling(stringRequest);
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

I have increase time from here..

```
 public class VoleyErrorHandling {

    public VoleyErrorHandling(StringRequest stringRequest) {

        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                1 * 60 * 1000,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    }
}
```

I don't know why it is happing. Is there any error for configuring 
Please help me

Comment: could you please post your crash log

Comment: are you able to reach to the URL/API End point(the one which you are trying to access using volley) using API tools such as Postman? If you cannot - then there is something wrong with your backend server - web service.

Comment: @AADProgramming Yes i am able to reach url